# Is there an easy way to change the text color of a UIBarButtonItem without using an image?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibarbuttonitem

Is there an easy way to change the text color of a UIBarButtonItem without using an UIImage as the background?

By default the text is always white. I'd like to make it black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is no.

You can't simply change the color of a `UIBarButtonItem` by setting one of its properties. You can set the `tintColor` property of the `UIToolBar` or `UINavigationBar` that contains the `UIBarButtonItem`s, but that also affects the color of the toolbar itself and doesn't offer too much customization.

If that doesn't work for you, a custom view as the other answers suggest is a fine idea.

Good luck!

Comment: Just to note, the tintColor property is not supported pre iOS 5.

Comment: Actually, according to Apple's docs, tintColor has been available since iOS 2.0

Comment: According to Apple's docs, not for `UIBarButtonItem` -
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/tintColor

Comment: That's not what I was suggesting in my answer, but you're right about that.

Answer (score 6):

Thank to IOS 5.0 you do not need to use images for that.You can set various text attributes with following code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

if ([button respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes:forState:)]) {

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               kTextColor,UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                               nil];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes                   
                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem and customize that one.

This is an example with custom graphics for a custom UIButton. The idea stays the same use `initWithCustomView` of the UIBarButtonItem to put something else in it which is easily customizable.

```
self.closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[closeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"webview_close_button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"webview_close_button_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 121, 36);
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAdViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem * aBarButtonAdClose = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:closeButton] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom view by using

`[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] - (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView]`