# Is there any way to change text color of UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I want to change text color of UIBarButtonItem,like Pinterest app(navigationItem.backBarButtonItem).
But here's almost same question.
[Is there an easy way to change the text color of a UIBarButtonItem without using an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652165/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-text-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-without-using#_=_)

So,Why text color of UIBarButtonItem is changed in Pinterest app?

Comment: Finaly,I want to change text color of buckButtonItem of UINavigationBar in UINavigationContoroller.

Answer (score 4):

Try `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:`

You can learn more from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @interface MyViewCOontroller : UIViewController {
  UILabel *lblTotCaratteri;
  }
```

In implementation

```
  UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
 lblTotCaratteri = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 15)];
 lblTotCaratteri.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

 lblTotCaratteri.textColor =[UIColor greyColor];
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't the direct way of doing this but you can achieve this by adding a UIBUtton to the customview of the UIBarButtonItem.

```
UIButton *backButton    =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame        =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40);
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];// Setting the background Image
[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Setting the title of the button
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];// Setting the text color.
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTaped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem =   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem   =   backButtonItem;
```

And this will give you a UIBarButtonItem with the text "Back" in red color.

Comment: Naveen, the tintColor affects the whole button, where as the question is about changing the text only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISegmentedControl to simulate the UIBarButtonItem. Make sure you have a segment control with single segment.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [YOUR_SEGMENTED_CONTROL removeAllSegments];
  [YOUR_SEGMENTED_CONTROL insertSegmentWithTitle:@"MyButton" atIndex:0 animated:NO];   
}
```

Retrieve the label of the UISegmentedControl and set the textColor to your preferred color

```
UILabel* lblText = [[[[YOUR_SEGMENTED_CONTROL subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
lblText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```